# How do I resolve this sql query

Tags: python, sql

```
cur.execute("UPDATE student SET Name=%s, Gender=%s, Father's Name=%s, D.O.B=%s, Course=%s, Year=%s, Phone No.=%s, E-mail=%s, Address=%s WHERE Uni Roll.No.=%s",(self.name_var.get(),self.gender_var.get(),self.fathers_name_var.get(),self.dob_var.get(),self.course_var.get(),self.year_var.get(),self.phone_no_var.get(),self.email_var.get(),self.text_address.get('1.0',END),self.Uni_Roll_No_var.get()))
```

This shows an error

> pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax  to use near ''s Name='Adarsh', D.O.B='20-03-2000', Course='BCom', Year='2013', Phone No.='...' at line 1") PS C:\Users"

Comment: Are you sure about your column names? They contain punctuation characters and spaces which is unusual...

Comment: Shouldn't django (or whatever this is) be able to do this without using raw sql queries?

Comment: You can't use `.`, `'` and `-` characters in column names, unless you quote the whole name with a tick character `\``. [Documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/identifier-names/)

Comment: The error message tells you how to resolve the query.

Comment: Yes adding ` solved the problem. ThankYou